# execute hooks inside a function in react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Can I use hooks inside a function? For example I have implemented the following code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component} from 'react';

export default class  App extends Component {
   checkdata_db(){ 
      const [booblenavalue,setboolenavalue]=useState(false); 
              useEffect(() => {             
              setboolenavalue(true)
            }, [])
            console.log(booblenavalue);         
   }
    render(){
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work. It throws the following error:

> Invalid hooks call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"
>    How can i run hooks inside checkdata_db method?

Comment: Hooks are for Functional Components. It doesn't work with classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Elly as @YoussoufOumar said , you cant use hooks in classes, it can only be done with functional comp:

You can convert it to like this :

Also you cant use `useEffect,useState` inside any conditional statements like if,else etc.

So you need to add useEffect outside any functions etc

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component} from 'react';

const   App = () =>  {
const [booblenavalue,setboolenavalue]=useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {             
              setboolenavalue(true)
            }, [])
   const checkdata_db = () => { 
       
            
            console.log(booblenavalue);         
   }
    return <View />
}
```

Hope it helps feel free for doubts